# Mapping JSON data in React.js

Tags: reactjs, json, database, rendering

I'm a student who is struggling to figure out how to get my data to appear on the screen in my React.js program. My JSON data is being brought in to my app through a secure source and I'm able to pull in the data and observe it in the console, but I am unable to render any data on the screen thus far. I'm convinced that if I just learn how to do this at least once, it will help me greatly in the future. Any insight that anyone is willing to give will be much appreciated.

I've tried useEffect to fetch the data previously and got terrible results. I'm now attempting to map through the data to render it on the screen, but I'm getting an error message: "data.map is undefined". Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';



class App extends React.Component {

    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            items: [],
            DataisLoaded: false
        };
    }

    
    componentDidMount() {
          axios
     .get("/.netlify/functions/getWisdomData")
            .then(response => response.data)
            .then((data) => {
       
                this.setState({
                    items: data,
                    DataisLoaded: true
                });
            })
    }

    render() {
        const { DataisLoaded, items } = this.state;
        if (!DataisLoaded) return <div>
            <h1> Loading.... </h1> </div> ;

        return (
        <div className = "App">
            <h1> ME-TIME Quotes </h1> {
        
                data.map((item) => (
                <ol key = { item.id } >
                    Name: { item.name },
                    Content: { item.content }
                    </ol>
                ))
            }
        </div>
    );
 }
}

export default App;
```

Error I'm getting on the screen on local host:

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR

[eslint] 
src\App.js
  Line 43:5:  'data' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

Error I'm getting in the console:

```
2App.js:41 Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at App.render (App.js:41:1)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:19752:1)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:19698:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21611:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
```

Previous code I've used that actually returns data in the console:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import axios from 'axios';


function App() {

  const [container, setContainer] = useState(null)

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const results = await axios.get('/.netlify/functions/getWisdomData')
    console.log(results)


  } 
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
  },[])

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      {container}
    </div>
  )


  }



 export default App;
```

Data I'm attempting  to render, as it appears in the console:

```
{data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: 'OK', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …}
config
: 
{transitional: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, adapter: ƒ, …}
data
: 
data
: 
6cc5e436-2197-4e4b-8ee7-b0a0b996dc5f
: 
content
: 
"Never forget your siblings! They were your first childhood friends!"
name
: 
"siblings"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
8f8dba11-1e6a-4ed7-a14f-699dc30ef616
: 
{content: 'You have one life to live ! Who gives life to you, make them proud!', name: 'live'}
40cf2100-27e0-47fc-87a4-dd9b88a880e6
: 
{content: 'No need to be envious of anyone! God has enough for everyone!', name: 'need'}
42e6b416-5c7f-408e-9034-52c6f4ec3150
: 
{content: 'Don’t say you are sorry unless you really really mean it! Sorry has two Rs!', name: 'really'}
45fa1ef5-f289-4495-a855-9ad89d747779
: 
{content: 'Writing can take place anywhere but it can have an impact everywhere!', name: 'write'}
76d52bce-b821-47f3-b4dc-4713b7ab568f
: 
{content: 'Abraham Lincoln once said “All that I am or hope t…e would have said if she lived a whole life span?', name: 'mother'}
310a707b-4ceb-47b5-8219-64ac9825e2cb
: 
{collection: 'Treat others the way you want to be treated. No one should be mistreated!', name: 'treat'}
534d4b2b-b00f-48a6-8b96-fd3960df89a5
: 
{collection: 'Make memories today. Photos are tomorrow’s memories!', name: 'make'}
4616ba2a-76e2-46aa-aee6-9632eb8a63ca
: 
{content: 'Dwell on happy thoughts!', name: 'dwell'}
7066f9ae-383d-4a2e-864b-a94bca7be9fd
: 
{content: 'Don’t worry about what everyone will say!  focus on the one person who really matters!', name: 'focus'}
1743027e-49f1-41e9-8f94-336924d48876
: 
{content: 'My mother did not have a lot ! But the little that…have with others and make them feel the same way.', name: 'have'}
a76b4a77-82ce-4b9a-8869-61c9569d609c
: 
{content: 'You may not always feel beautiful but you must not always go with your feelings.', name: 'feel'}
aa016a90-7762-4004-b7ea-4149c4d6ac21
: 
{content: 'Don’t brag about your past mistakes! Brag about the person who forgave your past mistakes!', name: 'brag'}
bca161ce-0834-4a9a-b015-c83913d00d31
: 
{content: 'Where there is VISION! PROVISION isn’t far away!', name: 'where'}
c2bf5690-bcc4-4d50-89a4-c9685ccd8b89
: 
{content: 'Spread love not rumors!', name: 'love'}
c6be9133-2015-4b4a-b5c7-2a56c9b11666
: 
{content: 'A lion is not the fastest in the jungle, but he is the most respected.', name: 'lion'}
c9b99567-d5a3-42b5-91a7-eb5574f6573d
: 
{content: 'Our mother wasn’t just concerned about having a ro… concerned about having all of us under one roof!', name: 'care'}
e2ead43a-424d-4226-9079-5bd681ce61f3
: 
{content: 'If your heart is not renewed, don’t follow it!', name: 'heart'}
efefb75a-2dd9-4df8-bbab-c9a72face7ba
: 
{content: 'I feel as though I won a million dollars just hear…  Make someone very happy, just give them a call!', name: 'feel'}
fe780062-1bdd-49ae-9ac8-fe775afa140e
: 
{content: "It Doesn't matter how small your place is! Make space for love!", name: 'space'}
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
pageState
: 
"JDQ2MTZiYTJhLTc2ZTItNDZhYS1hZWU2LTk2MzJlYjhhNjNjYQDwf_____B_____"
status
: 
200
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
headers
: 
AxiosHeaders {connection: 'close', date: 'Sun, 30 Oct 2022 14:16:27 GMT', transfer-encoding: 'chunked', x-powered-by: 'Express', Symbol(defaults): null}
request
: 
XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
status
: 
200
statusText
: 
"OK"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
```

If possible, I would like to render data on the screen of my React app using the code I included at the top of this post. I'm ready to learn where I've gone wrong with this.

Answer (score 0):

I've made some changes to the code you posted which used a function component with `useEffect` to fetch the data. While you were using `useEffect` correctly, you were not storing the data in the component's state, due to which the component never "updated" (or "re-rendered", as it is usually called so in React).

I renamed the `container` state to `data`, moved the fetching function inside `useEffect`, and updated it to store `response.data` (the `data` property contains the response body, which is what you want to render) in the `data` state variable.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch data and store in data state
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get('/.netlify/functions/getWisdomData')
      setData(response.data)
    }

    fetchData()
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      {data}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I tried above code in my app and received the following error:    react-dom.development.js:14887 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {status, pageState, data}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: Okay, can you replace `setData(response.data)` inside the `fetchData` function with `console.log(response.data)` and add the output in your question? I'm unsure about the shape of your data

Comment: Objectdata: 6cc5e436-2197-4e4b-8ee7-b0a0b996dc5f: {content: 'Never forget your siblings! They were your first childhood friends!', name: 'siblings'}8f8dba11-1e6a-4ed7-a14f-699dc30ef616: {content: 'You have one life to live ! Who gives life to you, make them proud!', name: 'live'}[[Prototype]]: ObjectpageState: "JDQ2MTZiYTJhLTc2ZTItNDZhYS1hZWU2LTk2MzJlYjhhNjNjYQDwf_____B_____"status: 200[[Prototype]]: Object